# Position components in KiCad for a test rig

Tags: kicad, production-testing

I'm designing a test rig for a product. There's a number of test pads and a power connector on the PCB, which I want to match up with a tester device, i.e. the tester PCB should have pogo pins and the mating power connector in matching places.

The question: given the PCB of the product, how do I export from KiCad, for example, a .dxf such that it has only a few of the components? I could simply export the whole PCB as .dxf and import that to the user.dwgs layer in the tester PCB, but this will have a lot of visual noise as all components are visible. Is there a way I could export only the few selected components (test pads and power connector), or perhaps some other easy way to guarantee that the tester PCB will match with the testee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *...or perhaps some other easy way to guarantee that the tester PCB
> will match with the testee*

The way I'd do it is this: -

- Save the design under a new name (say "fixture")
- Lock the mating components needed on the "fixture"
- Delete all the components apart from those needed
- Use this as the basis for your fixture design
- Develop the fixture design but,
- Make sure the component copper/pads/holes that align with the original PCB are position-locked on the fixture design.

Comment: The .dxf was just an example, no special need for that specifically.

Comment: @Timo I've removed that sentence.

Comment: This is of course essentially what I ended up doing. I was hoping for some clever way to make this even easier, but I'm not quite sure what that could have been, anyway... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I add another solution.

I'm using a combination of theses tools:

- KiCad
- FreeCAD

I'm not affiliated with these products, I'm just a user. BTW, they are open source.

1. I imported the artwork into FreeCAD. Here I joined the board and all components to one solid body. It's a boolean operation (union). The command is [Part Fuse](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/Part_Fuse).
   Now, it's one object and not thousands, it's now better handled within the CAD tool.
2. I duplicated the layer with pads (Cu- or Paste-mask-layer and put it on the tester-pcb.
   There you can design the test stuff. Align the pads and drills with the pads of your testee.

There is also a FreeCAD plugin for KiCad (a so called workbench):
[KiCad StepUp](https://www.kicad.org/external-tools/stepup/).
Here you can import board files from KiCad an push a design back to KiCAD.

You can also go some steps further:
You could model the whole tester pcb with all pogo pins attached, add the pcb-under-test to your design and verify how good they mate. With collision detection turned on.
I haven't tried it yet by myself. But I think this could by handy if you have pogo pins with different contact length.

FreeCAD can be found here: [www.freecadweb.org](https://www.freecadweb.org/)

The procedure is not tight to the mentioned tools. The artwork (Gerber, dxf) could be imported to any 3D-CAD-Tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [my fork of openfixture](https://github.com/mdeweerd/openfixture) where I added a `generate_kicad.py` script which is called from `GenFixture` when the `--kicad` option is added.

It generates a schematic and PCB with the pogopins placed on the PCB, and as far as I remember with 3D models for the pogopins, which were generated `3dmodels/create-steps.sh`.  I do not guarantee the 3D models are correct, but it suffices to update the `3dmodels/pogopins.scad` script to adjust the generation thereof an regenerate them.